# Definition of Constant current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, conductors

In the definition of constant current my manual is giving, the current through two sections of a conductor (depicted in the figure) is:

$i_1 = \int_{S_1} \mathbf{j_1} \cdot \mathbf{u_1} \text{d}S_1, \quad i_2 = \int_{S_2} \mathbf{j_2} \cdot \mathbf{u_2} \text{d}S_2$

[image]

The current is defined as constant if the following condition is verified:

$i_1 = i_2$

Shouldn't pass more charge per unit of time and hence more current through section $S_1$ than $S_2$ since the surface is wider?
the only explanation I can give is that the speed through $S_1$ is less than that through $S_2$ so to have
$v_1 S_1 = v_2 S_2$
but I don't figure out how this could be possibly be achieved.

Comment: Well... it's a *constant* current, no? If $i_1\neq i_2$ then the current has changed, ergo not constant.

Comment: Try to make use of the fact that the charge coming in through $S_1$ should be equal to the charge going out through $S_2$.

Answer (score 0):

> the only explanation I can give is that the speed through $S_1$ is
>   less than that through $S_2$ so to have $v_1 S_1 = v_2 S_2$ but I
>   don't figure out how this could be possibly be achieved.

It's achieved due to conservation of charge, that is, charge does not build up or decrease in the two conductors. It's called the continuity equation. For continuity (constant current) if  $S_1$ > $S_2$, then $v_2$ > $v_1$ in order to keep the current constant.

That the drift velocity of the charges is actually greater in the narrower section that the wider section may seem counter intuitive, but if you have ever driven on a highway and come to a section where one or more lanes are closed, you may notice that you speed up when you get to the restricted section of the highway. This speeding up is necessary to maintain the overall flow of traffic without the backing up of vehicles. In a similar way the speeding up of the charge in $S_2$ keeps the charge from "piling up" in $S_1$.

Hope this helps.